# How to generate debug symbols in android studio, to then upload it to google play

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-play-console

I follow this guide: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633#upload_file
So I added: android.defaultConfig.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL' in the beginning of app build.gradle, but I can't find the files in app/build/outputs/native-debug-symbols/variant-name/native-debug-symbols.zip. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Android studio version: 4.1.1

Comment: Is the native code from your app compiled by Android Gradle plugin or do you import it from some other precompiled libraries?

Comment: it's compiled by gradle